# Intercepting Traffic before CNAME redirection

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, dns, cname

I have the following situation:

A user connects to the domain: *test.com*

I would like this domain to redirect for example to *google.com*

To do this i have pointed a CNAME record to google.com: www google.com (TTL: automatic)

Would it be possible to intercept the traffic that comes in on test.com before it gets send to google.com ? (custom protocol, not http or https)

I have found a library called: native-dns which i think might host a dns server?

i configured it as followed:

```
"use strict";

var dns = require('native-dns'),
  tcpserver = dns.createTCPServer(),
  server = dns.createServer();

var onMessage = function (request, response) {
  console.log('request from:', request.address);
  var i;
  response.additional.push(dns.CNAME({
    name: 'www.mydomain.com',
    data: 'otherdomain.com'
  }));
  response.additional.push(dns.NS({
    name: 'ns1.mydomain.com',
    data: '127.0.0.1'
  }));

  response.send();
};

var onError = function (err, buff, req, res) {
  console.log(err.stack);
};

var onListening = function () {
  console.log('server listening on', this.address());
  //this.close();
};

var onSocketError = function (err, socket) {
  console.log(err);
};

var onClose = function () {
  console.log('server closed', this.address());
};

server.on('request', onMessage);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.on('socketError', onSocketError);
server.on('close', onClose);

server.serve(53, '127.0.0.1');
```

The thing i'm wondering is how i can actually make this dns server functional. I would like to ping www.mydomain.com and get otherdomain.com as answer.

At the moment I am using an ubuntu server with the node script running on. The ping will be executed from a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 2):

In this setup, you cannot intercept the traffic at *test.com*, because it is never directed at your server.

When a client want to connect to *test.com*, first it attempts to resolve *test.com* into an IP address by looking up *test.com*'s DNS A record. You have no such record, but a CNAME redirecting to the A record (or CNAME) of *www.google.com*. Depending on whether the DNS request was recursive (and in the overwhelming majority of cases, it *is* recursive), the client either receives the IP address of *www.google.com* or the CNAME reference which it then follows.

Notice how this whole name resolution process happens before any connection to your service is made: CNAME simply makes the client bypass any service you run.

Based on the code sample, you simply want to proxy all traffic arriving to your *test.com* server to Google and that's a perfectly good way to intercept traffic. All you have to do is to *not* to use a CNAME, because it represents forwarding at a different stage of network connections.

Comment: I would like to find a way where i do not have to proxy the service, proxying will cost too much server power because it's for a game.

Comment: @MaximGeerinck: Well, if you want to intercept the complete traffic, you need to receive the complete traffic one way or another. If you can manipulate the client network, this can be done at either endpoints or somewhere in between. However, if all you need to know is whether a given client attempted to connect to the service, there may be a way to do that -- let me know which case it is.

Comment: Thank you for your response, In the best case scenario i would need to know the first part of the traffic (such as the username used to login). But only knowing if a client tempts to connect is also a good option

Comment: This latter could be done through making each client connect to their own dedicated DNS name (e.g. `unique-token-for-user.example.org`) and monitoring DNS name resolution. Limitations apply (see my recent answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920352/get-dns-configuration-of-a-remote-host/). I realize this may not be possible or accurate enough, but that's the best I can think of to be done on your end. Of course if you can access the client computer/network, you have more options.

Comment: After a long while of searching i have perhaps found a suitable scenario but can not figure out if it's correctly reasoned. Please see my original question for the update